# Bug in autosize.js of textareas when loading value from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, whitespace, autosize

I am trying to create a **web-form that has the option to reload previously saved data**.

The problem is that when a large string of text that was entered into an autosized textarea has been saved and reloaded it adds a large amount of white space to the text area. [See before save, and after load pictures below]

### BEFORE SAVE:

[image: BEFORE SAVE]

### AFTER LOAD:

[image: AFTER LOAD]

The form data is loaded by PHP injection of the value as in the following example:

```
<textarea class='animated' name="courseTitle" id="courseTitle"><?PHP echo ($_POST['courseTitle']) ?></textarea>
```

The form can be seen in this link. http://pansycheung.com/forms/NewCourseProposal.php?C2EF=0

and data can be loaded into the form in the table below (found at the bottom of the form page).

### LOAD TABLE:

[image: LOAD TABLE]

SELECT THE FIRST FILE TO LOAD

> "Phillip Test EECS3603"

The white space disappears when doing one of the following.

- Type something into the test area
- Or adjusting the zoom in the browser

Any help with debugging suggestions would be *fantastic*.

go to ttp://pansycheung.com/forms/NewCourseProposal.php?C2EF=0 to test the form.

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, did you try 'triggering' the autosize?

```
$('#courseTitle').trigger('autosize.resize');
```

You initially have to initialize the autosize;

```
$('#courseTitle').autosize();
```

If that still doesn't work try putting the 'trigger' autosize in a setTimeOut();

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#courseTitle').trigger('autosize.resize');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works, but you can TRIM the value of the textarea with trim().
[TRIM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

You can also use this function in jquery, if this is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems that the white space is not actually part of the `string` added to the textarea, I suspect it is due to the autosize function.